# Is there a way of formulating a GREP find and replace so that the first sub-expression is not changed but the second sub-expression is?

Tags: grep, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I want to apply a paragraph style to the first character after a page break (second sub-expression). But I don't want this style to be applied to the page break (first sub-expression). Is there any way of doing this?

I tried this:

Find: (~P)(.)

Change: $1~h$2 (change format to first para style)

I also tried

Change: $2 (change format to first para style)

Both search and replaces changed both subexpressions to the first para style.

Basically, I just want the first para after a page break to *not* be indented. All other paragraphs are indented. When I search for text after a page break it changes the text of the page break which means the last paragraph of text on a page is also not indented, which is not what I want.

Comment: Technically the 'Positive Lookbehind' expression `(?<=~M)(.)` should do the work but somehow it doesn't. I'd propose to do it with two steps. **Step 1** — insert some unique symbols (`##` for example) at the start of the paragraphs: `(~M)(.)` --> `$1##$2`. **Step 2** — remove the unique symbols and apply the style: `##(.)` --> `$1 [with the paragraph style]`

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned Positive Lookbehind didn't work -- sorry!

Ah, yes, that should do it. Thanks!